# Spring MVC Controller Redirection With Twilio

Tags: java, spring, twilio

I have a twilio application that I'm trying to split between spanish and english using the same code. The idea is simple, split the XML into two functions that assign either the spanish version or english. That is fine, however I've run into an issue on redirecting the controller.

All the answers I saw said to `return "redirect:/route"` but with Twilio, this merely causes the phone to say in english "redirect colon slash route" and then hangup the call

What am I doing wrong?

```
//assign english data and redirect to IVR greeting method
@RequestMapping(value = "/ivr/en")
public String ivrLangEn(@RequestParam("CallSid") String callID) {
    //english xml string assignments here
    return "redirect:/irv";
}

//assign spanish data and redirect to IVR greeting method
@RequestMapping(value = "/ivr/sp")
public String ivrLangSp(@RequestParam("CallSid") String callID) {
    //spanish xml string assignments here
    return "redirect:/ivr";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/ivr", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
/*
 * Main greeting method. Display greeting and default to question one
 * @return returns the XML for the greeting and question one
 */
@ResponseBody
public String greeting(@RequestParam("CallSid") String callID) {
    repository.save(new Feedback(callID));
    String xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>" +
        "<Response>"+
            "<Say>Hello.</Say>"+
            one +
        "</Response>";
    return xml;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out Twilio simply outputs a string return from the controller. I found that I need to use a `ModelAndView` redirect like so:

```
return new ModelAndView("redirect:/ivr");
```

Comment: Is that greeting() method? Removing the `@ResponseBody` also works :)
With `@ResponseBody`, Spring with output the String to the ServletResponse, and that's your issue.

Comment: I added in `@ResponseBody` while looking for an answer. With twilio, it said it regardless. Now it's not needed lol

Comment: Check it out here http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ResponseBody.html and here, for a concrete example http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-responsebody

Comment: Sorry, I misread your code, do ignore my remark about `@ResponseBody`, but won't hurt to read about the `redirect` prefix :) http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-redirecting-redirect-prefix